# MYSQL - not getting correct data MAX

Tags: mysql

I have a list of cases containing agencies. All agencies contain tasks which have a status assigned to it. 0 = complete, 1 = ongoing and 2 = overdue.

I am trying to show for all cases if there is any tasks overdue. At the moment my query shows the status as 1, even though there are some tasks overdue.

SQL FIDDLE HERE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4394/3

I don't know what I need to change in order to pull out the correct data. Any ideas?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: That's because you are using `group by` incorrectly (and MySQL - as the only DBMS - allows such an "illegal" use). See here for details: http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html

Comment: +1 for providing your own sqlfiddle.

Comment: +1 again for giving us your own sqlfiddle.

Comment: +1 Indeed it's a good practice...

Comment: @Pooshonk Question... can a task be assigned to two agencies? It seems to me you do not need the many-to-many table "`cases_agency_association`". You could have a foreign key `agency_id` inside of task and save yourself one more table and one more join...

Comment: It can but it isn't linked to the same agency, so the status is for every task association rather than the task alone. I have managed to fix my query now, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring that you're writing a MySQL-only `SELECT`, your joins are wrong; you're joining `cc.case_ID` on `caa.ID` when you actually want `caa.case_ID`:

```
SELECT cc . * , a.ID, MAX(cta.status) AS current_status
FROM cases_complete cc, agencies a, cases_agency_association caa,
  cases_task_association cta
WHERE cc.case_ID = caa.case_ID
AND caa.agency_ID = a.ID
AND cta.agency_association_ID = caa.ID
GROUP BY cc.case_ID
```

However @meewoK's approach, and the comment about not abusing `GROUP BY` are both worth thinking through from the point of view of coming up with something clearer, more maintainable, and hopefully more portable / future compatible as well.

Comment: I have just figured this out for myself a moment ago. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query is right, the problem is that you're getting info from multiple tables but, you don't have enough records in all of them, basically you have IDs on your `cases_agency_association` table up to 6, and the records from your `cases_task_association` table where the `status` is 2, all have IDs greater than 6...

Answer (score 0):

Would not this solve your basic problem:

```
select * from `cases_task_association` where status =2;
```

This is without the joins etc, but the query above is the base for providing all cases that are overdue and not completed.

Comment: No i need to show all of the cases regardless of the status. The client wants an indicator of the statuses of all tasks, overdue ongoing or complete, but I have managed to fix it. Thank you regardless :)